# How to avoid duplicating statements with grouping functions?

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

I have a t-sql query where sum function is duplicated.
How to avoid duplicating those statements?

```
select 
    Id,
    sum(Value)
from
    SomeTable
group by 
    Id
having
    sum(Value) > 1000
```

Comment: The group by sum(value) doesn't really look good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like table aliasing is not supported.
I think `with` should work:

```
with tmptable (id,sumv)
as
(select
    Id,
    sum(Value) as sumv
from
    SomeTable
group by 
    Id  
)
select
    id,
    sumv 
from
    tmptable
where
   sumv>1000
```

And a fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d3f2/2

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the sum(Value) from the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY 1, 2` to group by (in this case) the first and second columns, and thus avoid duplication in the `GROUP BY` clause.